# Data Table export PDF styling

Tags: datatables

Does anyone know how you go about styling the PDF generated from the Buttons extension? I specifically just want to td align right.How can I use colspan in datatable?

Thank you

my code is

```
                     $('#reporTable').DataTable({

                        "paging" : false,
                        "ordering": false,
                        "info" : false,
                        "searching" : false,

                        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                        tableTools: {
                        "sSwfPath": "/javascripts/js/dataTables/tools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",

                        "aButtons": [
                        {
                        "sExtends": "pdf",
                        "sTitle": $filename,
                        "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                        "sPdfMessage": $out_name+":" + msg
                        },

                        ],

                        }

                        });
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the example code of it.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
   title: 'My title' + '\n' + 'a new line',
   customize: function(doc) {
     doc.styles.title = {
       color: 'red',
       fontSize: '40',
       background: 'blue',
       alignment: 'center'
     }
     doc.styles.tableHeader = {
       color: 'red',
       background: 'blue',
       alignment: 'right'
     }
     doc.styles.tableBodyEven = {
       background: 'yellow',
       alignment: 'right'
     }
     doc.styles.tableBodyOdd = {
       background: 'blue',
       alignment: 'right'
     }
    doc.styles.tableFooter = {
       background: 'blue',
       alignment: 'right'
     }
    doc.styles['td:nth-child(2)'] = { 
       width: '100px',
       'max-width': '100px'
     }
   }  
 }]
})
```